# Angular to React - How to replace use of pound sign (hashtag)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-boilerplate

I am about to redo code switching from Angular 1 to React. I have been using [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) for a while, which uses React Router v3, and I really like the setup. My Angular project uses URLs like **example.com/#/about** and I really don't like the concept of the `#` sign so I want to make the URL look like **example.com/about**.

The problem is some URLs have been given out to the public so I would like for them to be backward-compatible. For example, if a user goes to **/#/about**, then they will be automatically redirected to **/about**.

If you know the React Boilerplate's ecosystem, that would be helpful. I know the concept of redirecting is simple, but I would like to do this in a clean way within the boilerplate. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is documented pretty clearly in the react-router v3 docs: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#preserving-urls

Comment: Thanks for that link. I never ran across this and it's a start, but React Boilerplate uses `react-router-redux` also and the routes are declared differently. I will continue to try figuring it out but if anyone can help in regards to React Boilerplate, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Calvin's comment above, it sent me down a different thought process. I found out that React Boilerplate allows redirects like so:

```
onEnter: (_nextState, replace, next) {
    replace('/something');
    next();
}
```

This is to be placed inside of the **routes.js** file. The link to the question/answer where I found this answer is [here](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1280).

### Edit

The exact answer ended up being this function:

```
const sniffHash = (nextState, replace, next) => {
    if (nextState.location.hash !== '') {
        let path = nextState.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        replace(path);
    }
    next();
}
```

in which I used the variable name on my home route like so:

```
path: '/',
name: 'home',
onEnter: sniffHash,
getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    //React Boilerplate router stuff
}
```

The only caveat is if I needed anchor links, then I would have to figure something out. Not ideal, but it may help someone who has to make this type of transition.